# SWFUpload - how to resize image by filling in whitespace if size does not match fixed size

Tags: image, resize, size, swfupload, fixed

I need to have full original image of any size, resized in to a fixed sized area.

I'm using SWFUpload for this. I haven't figured out how is this possible?

---

Example

I have image sized 200 X 500 px.

It has to fit to fixed sized image area of 500 X 500 px.

In the end image I'd like to have empty area which is sized of 300 X 0 px to show white background.

---

Any ideas if this is actually possible?

Comment: Any suggestions of a way to do this welcome. We can do this at the browser front end (jquery or similar) - or maybe backend with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using the current flash api. The latest (beta) version allows only resizing.